# Trouble requesting Spotify access token [Bad Request]

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, spotify

I am trying to a request a spotify access token using the procedure defined under '**Client Credentials Flow**'  on the [Spotify developer page](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/authorization-guide/#client_credentials_flow),

Here is my current implementation (Currently returns http 400 error):

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    var requestBody = new StringContent(
        "grant_type:client_credentials", 
        Encoding.UTF8, 
        "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    var requestEncrypted = Convert.ToBase64String(
        Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(ClientId + ":" + ClientSecret));

    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(
         "Authorization", 
         $"Basic {requestEncrypted}");

    var tokenResult = await client.PostAsync(TokenEndpoint, requestBody); 
}
```

I have tried other ways for formatting the request body including as json (Note: changing the encoding type to 'application/json' results in a http 415 error (media not supported)

Comment: What is your `TokenEndpoint` value?

Comment: @ShaunLuttin 'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For one, you need to use equals not a colon.

```
grant_type=client_credentials
```

Here is an [example POST from the RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.4.2).

```
POST /token HTTP/1.1
Host: server.example.com
Authorization: Basic czZCaGRSa3F0MzpnWDFmQmF0M2JW
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

grant_type=client_credentials
```

Comment: Stuck for 30 mins by a single character, Thank you!